Applications opened from Terminal not coming to foreground/focus
I'm a longtime MacBook user and I interface with the OS primarily from the Terminal command line.  I recently started a new job where I was issued a fairly locked down M3 but I have managed to install a few free tools on it, and I've installed a version of SlickEdit that I purchased on my own dime.
On all previous macs, I was able to set an alias to the SlickEdit executable and it would open a file and SlickEdit to the foreground/focus:
alias vs='/Applications/SlickEditPro2022.app/Contents/MacOS/vs '

On this Mac (Sonoma 14.7 (23H124)), opening a file this way works, but it does NOT bring the SlickEdit window to the foreground/focus.
I have another alias, "open ." which opens finder in the directory I am in in Terminal and it fails in the same way, not bringing the window to the foreground.
alias exp='open .'

Here is my OSX about:

Advice?
Update
This question remains unanswered.
I tried the suggestion in the @0stone0 answer but I cannot unselect "Secure Keyboard Entry" in the Terminal menu but it cannot be deselected.

I also tried using open as a suggested answer to another question suggested, but that did not work either.

Wow, all I got was one negative vote without comment.  Where is the love?
Person who gave the negative vote, the definition for that is "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".  Can you advise what part isn't clear?  And yes, I did research...didn't find any recent answers and even older answers did not help.

In System Settings > Privacy & Security > Automation check under "Terminal" if "Finder" and "System Events" are selected on.

This question is similar to: Mac OS X: Bring GUI applications to foreground when launched from the command line. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Your issue is probably caused by the Secure Keyboard Entry options being enabled.
If this is enabled, eg open /tmp will not get in focus.
Disabling this option will once again focus opened windows.



Hmm, for some reason selecting this menu option does NOT disable Secure Keyboard Entry.  Is there another way to disable it?
Give you an upvote for taking the time to answer...thanks.

Mm thats weird, check your permissions to ensure terminal has all access. I'm able to toggle that one just fine. Maybe reboot?
